# SDWebImageDownloader : The image download fails with error 404

Tags: iphone

The images are stored at an server requiring authorization. Is there any header value that we missed here or could you ust help me resolve this issue or point out to the right direction.

SDWebImageDownloader * downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader];

```
    [downloader setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [downloader setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [downloader setValue:[self getAuthorizationHeaderValue] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [downloader setValue:@"UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Encoding"];

    [downloader downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] options:SDWebImageDownloaderHighPriority progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
         NSLog(@"\n Progress download ......");
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
        if (image && finished) {
            NSLog(@"Success downloading image, returning image........");
            [subscriber sendNext:image];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }
        else if (error && finished) {
            NSLog(@"Error downloading image, returning placeholder image........");
            [subscriber sendError:error];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

`The image download fails with error 404` means your URL image is not exist on the specified server path. You can double check, by trying open that URL in your computer's browser, beware, even if it'll showing you an image for that bad URL, clear your cache of your browser and then reload that URL.

Comment: Thanks :) this is the same issue. The images are nt available on the server.

Comment: Welcome :) If my answer helps you then you can always mark it as accepted so it will be helpful for everyone in future.